# How I Can Set Background For Body?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I want to set a background image for the body but it does not work correctly. my Colleague sent me a SVG file and I have to set it as background but the problem is that the image is not in its place.
This is what I have to set in adobe xd

---

[image: in adobe xd]

---

and this is what I have.

---

[image: in my html]

---

as you see there is some space around the background how i can solve this problem.

---

this is my code.

---

```
<body>
 some code
</body> 


 body{
   background:url('../../Images/newback.svg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;

   }
```

Comment: Try adding width attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because of margin or padding

try setting `margin` & `padding` to 0; and background-size to 100%.

```
 body{
   background:url('../../Images/newback.svg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;

   }
```

Comment: You don't want to use this solution, you will be able to see margins if the screen does not have the same aspect ratio as the image, `background-size: cover` is a better option, with a media query with a specific background for portrait / mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-size: cover;`
May not work on older browsers, also take a look here [CSS TRicks](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to a background  % width issue

```
background-size: 100%
```

Try adding that and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

a good rule is to set the margin and padding to 0 at the begining.

`*{
Margin: 0;
Padding: 0;
}`